# How to check current HP value in dark souls 2?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Unlike Dark Souls 1 the player stats in Dark Souls 2 shows only max HP value. **Is there a way to check current HP (health points) value in DS2?**

P.S. If there is not, then is there a way to check whether you've reached a point when you don't lose hp after deaths? It is 50% hp I belive, but it is hard to say looking at the hp bar whether it is 50% or 55%.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get a number for your current health, only your overall health, which can be found in the Player Status page of the menu.

[image: Overall health]

Additionally, the overall health loss *is* capped at 50% of your total, and will not drop below that. From the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/hp) (Emphasis mine)

> In addition, there is an item that decreases the total percentage of your health bar that can become locked to 25%, **rather than 50%** (Ring of Binding).

Comment: So how do I know whether the max hp loss has reached the cap of 50% of not? The losses are quite small (5%?) and hardly distingushable on the hp bar.

Comment: btw: There is a guy on youtube who is testing the limits of DarkSouls and he did make a Video about HP in DS2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgwp1i7Dofs

Comment: @klm123 unfortunately there's no *real* way to determine that in-game. The best you can do is just by sight comparison.